# How can i do a date range filter in datatables in angular 7?

Tags: angular, filter, datatables

I want to do code like this https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/custom-range-search ...But with a date and I don't know how. I try to do the same thing but changing the variables, but I can't.
Actually, I have the same code of the link

```
     @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
  public logs: LogsTabla[];
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  min: number;
  max: number;

  constructor(private _auditoriaService: AuditoriaService) { }

  ngOnInit():void {
    $.fn['dataTable'].ext.search.push((settings, data, dataIndex) => {

      const id = parseFloat(data[0]) || 0; // use data for the id column
      if ((isNaN(this.min) && isNaN(this.max)) ||
        (isNaN(this.min) && id <= this.max) ||
        (this.min <= id && isNaN(this.max)) ||
        (this.min <= id && id <= this.max)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
```

and the HTML

```
<form (submit)="filterById()">
          <label>
            Min
            <input type="number" name="min" id="min" [(ngModel)]="min"  />
          </label>
          <label>
            Max
            <input type="number" name="max" id="max" [(ngModel)]="max" />
          </label>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Filter by ID</button>
        </form>
        <br />
```

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly what you want to do and where the problem is?  We should not have to go to another website or repo to understand your question, in general.  Also, making your question more clear and concise could lead you to solve it on your own!  Thanks :)

Comment: yes sure, i want to do a filter by date range in datatables.
i have a table of logs with a date and i want to filter the logs by the range of date that i want. 
i search in a lot of pages but nobody says how to do it in angular 7